# Python OR behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ran into an issue while trying to make aliases for an input.

```
inp = "h" #the input
if inp == "s": 
    print("stand")
elif inp == "h": 
    print("hit")
else:
    print("else")
```

This code behaves exactly as expected *s* makes it take the first branch *h* second and anything else the third. But when i add **or** into the if statement

```
inp = "h"
if inp == "s" or "stand":
    print("stand")
elif inp == "h":
    print("hit")
else:
    print("else")
```

the first branch gets picked regardless on the input provided. What I expected to happen was to get the same logic as before. Am I misusing OR or this should work but doesnt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not *quite* using or correctly. I made the same mistake with my first time using logic, so I wouldn't stress it too much. The correct usage isn't much different:

```
inp = "h"
if inp == "s" or inp == "stand":
    print("stand")
elif inp == "h":
    print("hit")
...
```

The way conditions work is that for each condition, python basically puts on `is True` at the end. So `if inp == "s"` would basically be `if inp == "s" is True`. That would explain why inputting `stand` wouldn't work, since it would be checking if "stand" was equal to True.

Edit: sorry, my above statement is incorrect. What the program is checking for is if "stand" is a "valid" item. That might not be the correct terminology, but something that wouldn't be valid would be an empty list, empty string, or the keyword `None`. Since "stand" is valid, it counts as being True, and thus the first branch is always taken.

Comment: Please don't re-answer FAQs. There's a reason close-as-duplicate exists: so we can use existing, maximally-canonical answers for commonly asked questions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry about that. I wasn't aware that this question was a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**You've misunderstood the `or` syntax**

In python all empty strings, lists, dicts, etc, evaluate to `False`:

```
x = []
if x: # Evaluates to False
   pass
```

In this example, `x`, being empty is `False`. According to this behavior any *non-empty* list, string, etc, evaluates to `True`:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
if x: # Evaluates to True!
   print("This will print!")
```

Your code is asking is `inp` equal to `"s"`, *or* is the string `"stand"` *non-empty*. The string `"stand"` is non-empty and thus the statement evaluates to `True`. To fix this, try asking is `inp` equal to `"s"`, or is `inp` equal to `"stand"`:

```
inp = "h"
if inp == "s" or inp == "stand": # Note the edit... This will evaluate to False.
    print("stand")
elif inp == "h":
    print("hit")
else:
    print("else")
```